# Can't get data from FirestoreImpl to repository or viewmodel in Android dagger hilt

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am trying to get a list from Firestore with dagger hilt in android .I got data in FirestoreServiceImpl but when I call it from repository class or viewmodel I get null.Is there any problem with my hilt implementation ? How can I get data in repository ?

**AppModule**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideFirebaseAuth(): FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideFireStore(): FirebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMainActivity(): MainActivity = MainActivity.getInstance() as MainActivity

}
```

**ServiceModule**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class ServiceModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindAccountService(
        authServiceImpl: AuthServiceImpl
    ): AuthService


    @Binds
    abstract fun bindFirestoreService(
        firestoreServiceImpl: FirestoreServiceImpl
    ): FirestoreService
}
```

**FirestoreService**

```
interface FirestoreService {

    val responseState: MutableStateFlow<Response>
    suspend fun getAllCurrentBanner():MutableLiveData<List<BannerModel>>
}
```

**FirestoreServiceImpl**

```
class FirestoreServiceImpl @Inject constructor(private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore) :
    FirestoreService {

    private val BANNER_COLLECTION = "BANNER"


    override val responseState: MutableStateFlow<Response>
        get() =  MutableStateFlow(Response.NotInitialized)

    override suspend fun getAllCurrentBanner(): MutableLiveData<List<BannerModel>> {
        val mutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<BannerModel>> = MutableLiveData()
        firestore.collection(BANNER_COLLECTION).whereEqualTo("isShow", true)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                val a=value?.toObjects(BannerModel::class.java)
                Log.e("TAG impl", "getAllCurrentBanner: ${a?.get(0)?.image}", )
                mutableLiveData.postValue(value?.toObjects(BannerModel::class.java))
  //getting data here
                Log.e("TAGbanner", "getAllCurrentBanner: ${value?.isEmpty}", )
            }
        return mutableLiveData
    }
}
```

**FireStoreRepository**

```
class FireStoreRepository @Inject constructor(private val firestoreService: FirestoreService){

    fun responseState()=firestoreService.responseState
     suspend fun getAllBanner(): MutableLiveData<List<BannerModel>> {
         Log.e("TAG repo", "getAllBanner: ${firestoreService.getAllCurrentBanner().value}", )
       
            //here I get null
       return firestoreService.getAllCurrentBanner()

    }

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(val repository: FireStoreRepository):ViewModel() {

   // val state: MutableStateFlow<Response> = repository.responseState()

   // private val _banners=MutableLiveData<List<BannerModel>>()




    var job: Job? = null
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->

        Log.e("TAG1", "Error : ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
    }


     fun getAllBanner(): MutableLiveData<List<BannerModel>> {
         val bannerLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<BannerModel>>()
        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler).launch {
           val response=repository.getAllBanner()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
               bannerLiveData.postValue(response.value)
               // _banners.value=response.value
                Log.e("TAGbannerAll", "getAllBanner: ${response.value}", )
                //here I get null
            }
        }

         return bannerLiveData


    }
}
```

**Model Class**

```
class BannerModel(
    val bannerId:String?="",
    val image:String?="",
    val isShow:Boolean?=false,
    val title:String?="",
    val shopId:String?="",
)
```

**Home Screen**

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    homeScreenViewModel: HomeScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val bannerListState by homeScreenViewModel.getAllBanner().observeAsState()
    val bannerlist = mutableListOf<BannerModel>()
    bannerListState?.let { bannerlist.addAll(it) }

    Log.e("TAGbanner", "HomeScreen: $bannerlist", )



    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        HorizontalPagerBanner(bannerlist)
       
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Where exactly in this code, are you getting null?

Comment: In HomeScreenViewModel ; when I call getAllBanner() method it return null here ,